# Can WSL2 be downloaded, installed on Windows 10 1909 (OS Build 18363.900) with WSL1 activated, without Store access?

Tags: windows-10, installation, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

Is it possible to download and install WSL2 on `Windows 10 1909 (OS Build 18363.900)` with WSL1 activated, without Store access. Notes:

1. Every suggestions to do this `wsl --set-default-version <Version>` to simply make WSL2 the default simply outputs, effectively, `wsl --help` content
2. [This article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/wsl-2-support-is-coming-to-windows-10-versions-1903-and-1909/) suggests WSL2 will/has been backported to "`Windows 10 ...1909`"
3. With one (crucial?!) exception, Windows Update is reporting all available updates are installed. Exception being `2021-05 Cumulative Update for Windows 10 Version 1909 for x64-based Systems (KB5003169) -Error 0x800f0982`. The **update is available for manual download and install**: https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB5003169%20x64%2010 however it fails to install, returning the same error code
4. Successfully ran `dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:VirtualMachinePlatform /all /norestart`
5. Successfully installed the "Linux kernel update" `https://wslstorestorage.blob.core.windows.net/wslblob/wsl_update_x64.msi`

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to download and install WSL2 on Windows 10 1909 (OS Build 18363.900) with WSL1 activated without Store access?

No, enabling WSL2 on the current minor build you have installed is impossible.

> This article suggests WSL2 will/has been backported to "Windows 10 ...1909

WSL2 was indeed backported to 1903 and 1909.  However, it's only accessible, if you installed the cumulative update that increased build to either 18362.1049  or 18363.1049.  **The solution of course is to update the installation to the last cumaltive update that was released for 1909.**

As indicated by the blog article you don't have the required update that introduced WSL2 to your version of Windows.

> You can check if you have this backport by verifying the minor build number of your Windows build. To do this, right click on the start menu, click ‘Run’ and then type in ‘winver’ and hit enter. The first number before the . is your major build number, so for version 1903 this will read 18362. The number after the . is your minor build number, and this will let you know whether you have the backport on your machine. This backport has the minor build number: 1049. To summarize, if your minor build number is 1049 or higher on Windows builds 18362 or 18363, then you have the backport and the ability to run WSL 2 distros.
>
> [image]

> Windows Update is reporting all updates available are installed

All updates are not actually installed, even when 1909 was supported back in 2022, 18363.900 would have been more than 22 months out of date (April 2022 (18363.2212) vs June 2020 (18363.900). **KB5003169 is more than 12 months out of date.**

**The problem you will have is that all updates for 1903 and 1909 no longer exist in the Windows Update Catalog.  This means you won't be able to find the cumulative update you need to enable WSL2 on 1909.**

0x800f0982 indicates Windows Update corruption, likely due to the unsupported status of 1909, and the fact your system is more than 3 years out of date.

Comment: Thanks - I did miss that it required the minor build number of 1049.